# Detecting/redirecting browser that does not support SNI with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, sni

I set up SNI/SSL on my app engine app using [this excellent page](http://blog.neutrondrive.com/posts/236948-undocumented-guide-to-using-ssl-on-google-app-engine).

I'd like my site to work for people still on older browsers that don't support SNI.  Ideally, I'd like to detect these older browsers and redirect them to https://myapp.appspot.com.

I've seen some posts about people doing this with Apache rewrite rules, but of course you can't do that with app engine.

The ever so unhelpful GAE documentation states

> We recommend detecting browsers that do not support SNI and
>   recommending a browser that supports it.

but doesn't give us any clue how to do that.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [SSL with Virtual IP](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl#virtual_ip_vip).

The reason for this is that older browsers that don't support SNI simply don't send *any* indication of the server name (host) that was requested - only the IP address.  Since typically Google hosts many web applications on their externally advertised and shared IP addresses there is simply no way for Google to send the request to your application in that shared scenario.